# In cassandra, is it possible to control to which physical machine vnodes are assigned?

Tags: cassandra

I am just trying to learn a little more about vnodes, and I am curious. I like the idea of having many vnodes on a single physical node, but I would like to be able to control which physical machine is a replica for each vnode. For example, let's assuming that I have 8 physical nodes and RF=3. I'd like to place the replicas for each node such that they are laid out in the following way:

```
Let capital letters be physical nodes
Let lowercase letters be vnodes. Vnodes in parens are located on the
  corresponding physical machine.

A(ablmno)
B(acdnop)
C(abcefp)
D(bcdegh)
E(defgij)
F(fghikl)
G(hijkmn)
H(jklmop)
```

The important thing to note is the any vnode is only replicated to machines that are within 4 nodes of one another. For example, `a` is replicated to ABC, `b` is replicated to ACD, `d` is replicated to BDE, and so on.

I would like to be able to keep the replication within a certain range of physical nodes so that I don't get into a situation where there are no three phsical node sets that contain zero vnodes in common (meaning that losing any three nodes on the cluster guarantees data loss). In the example above, nodes ADE can be lost and not cause data loss (assuming all replicas are up-to-date) due to the fact that the intersection of the vnodes for A, D, and E is an empty set. Here's a proof by python of my previous statement:

```
>>> A = set(['a', 'b', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'])
>>> D = set(['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'h'])
>>> E = set(['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'j'])
>>> A.intersection(D).intersection(E)
set([])
```

I understand that this would probably cost both node bootstrap speed and node repair speed, but I'd be able to limit the probability that node failures of # >= RF cause data loss to something under 100%. The main reason I am interested in this issue is that the possibility of multi-node failures increases as the number of machines in a cluster increases, so I'd like to limit the probability of data loss due to a three node failure as a cluster gets larger.

Is this possible with `Cassandra` (latest version 1.2.8 as of this writing)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specifying a comma separated list of tokens as the initial_token in cassandra.yaml on each node.

I think what you are referring to is known as the distribution factor (DF) - the number of nodes a node shares replicas with.  Without vnodes (equivalently setting num_tokens to 1), DF=2RF-1.  With vnodes and a random assignment of tokens (which is what happens if you don't specify any as initial_token), DF=N (with high probability (w.h.p.)), where N is the number of nodes.

There is a tension here - low DF means multiple simultaneous node failures are less likely lead to data loss or unavailability.  But low DF means when new nodes are added, the cluster won't remain balanced.  Also it means the rebuild time (time to run `nodetool removetoken` to create an extra copy of a node's vnodes) when a node fails is large, because the set of nodes that can be involved in the rebuild is low.  DF=N means all nodes in the cluster can participate in the rebuild, giving optimal rebuild time.

Rather than just thinking about simultaneous node failures, what you probably care about is a node failing, then another failing before that node had recovered.  If the recovery time is low then the window where you can lose data is small.

As you say, having more nodes means the probability of having multiple failures close together increases.  However, the fall in rebuild time as number of nodes increases more than compensates for this, at least under the (obviously false but often a good approximation) assumption of independent failures.  This is proved in my [blog post](http://www.acunu.com/2/post/2012/10/improving-cassandras-uptime-with-virtual-nodes.html).

The argument above shows that high DF decreases downtime.  Often service reliability is measured in number of 9s of uptime.  If this is true of your service then you want high DF.

However, you may want to decrease the probability of data being unavailable (temporarily, when recovery does not require streaming data) for any period within some time frame.  Maybe your contract says if any data cannot be read at any point you are penalised, but they don't care about how long it takes to recover.  In that case you want low DF.

Note the distinction between permanent and temporary failures.  If a node has failed permanently, you need to rebuild so want high DF.  If a node has failed temporarily and can recover on its own, you want low DF to minimize the probability of data being unavailable.

In the real world, failures are correlated to some extent, which makes simultaneous failures more likely.  As an extreme example, you might have some VMs running Cassandra on the same physical host.  Failures of these VMs will be extremely strongly correlated.  If you have this you want to choose your tokens so that no two VMs on the same physical host have replicas in common.  But apart from that you want to have your DF as high as possible if you want the benefits of vnodes.

A less extreme example is for multiple datacenters, where you want to ensure there is a replica in each.  This is what Cassandra's NetworkTopologyStrategy does.  This helps to mitigate the correlated failure of a whole datacenter becoming unavailable.

In summary, for totally independent failures, having maximum DF gives lowest probability of data loss.  To get this, use random tokens.  Having low DF gives lowest probability of data being temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra the replication is handled by the [snitch and it comes with a set of available options](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchesAbout_c.html), e.g.`SimpleSnitch`, `PropertyFileSnitch`, `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`, `EC2Snitch`, `EC2MultiRegionSnitch`. Anyways to achieve exactly the scenario you want you might need to create your own snitch (and keep in mind all other requirements that replication should accomplish)